# Temporal Database with Django Rest Framework using perform_update

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, temporal-database

We are trying to implement a temporal database so that we are able to track changes made

All our models have the following fields

```
vt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='VT', default=datetime(3000, 12, 31, 23, 00, 00, 000000))  # Value To
vflag = models.IntegerField(db_column='VFlag', default=1)  # Version Flag 1 = Current, 0 = Old
```

When using the Django rest framework I’ve tried to modify the perform_update in my viewset to duplicate the existing record, make the updates and then set temporal fields appropriately.

It works when I have 1 record and the first update

However once I try and make a second update it fails and create a duplicate of the changes and overrides the very first record.

Original Record

```
Currency = AUD, VFlag = 1, VT = time1
```

Perform update - success

```
Currency = USD, VFlag = 1, VT = time2

Currency = AUD, VFlag = 0, VT = time1
```

Next perform update currently produces  - fails

```
Currency = GBP, VFlag = 1, VT = time3

Currency = GBP, VFlag = 1, VT = time3

Currency = USD , VFlag = 0, VF = time2
```

Expected update output

```
Currency = GBP, VFlag = 1, VT = time3

Currency = USD, VFlag = 0, VT = time2

Currency = AUD, VFlag = 0, VT = time1
```

Is a temporal database a possibility in django rest?

Is anybody able to please point in the right direction

Below is my view set code

```
class OptionMasterViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
serializer_class = OptionMasterSerializer
paginate_by = None
queryset = OptionMaster.objects.filter(vflag=1)
# queryset = OptionMaster.objects.all()

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = OptionMaster.objects.filter(vflag=1)
    contractcode = self.request.query_params.get('contractcode', None)
    if contractcode is not None:
        queryset = queryset.filter(contractcode=contractcode, vflag=1)
    return queryset

def perform_update(self, serializer):

    changes = serializer.validated_data
    original_object = serializer.instance

    vt = datetime.now()

    changes['vf'] = vt

    #Build the old record
    old_record = {}
    for field in original_object._meta.get_fields():           
        old_record[field.name] = getattr(original_object, field.name)

    old_record['vflag'] = 0                
    old_record['vt'] = vt

    old_record = OrderedDict(old_record)

    #Save the new rrecord
    serializer.save()

    #Create the old record
    obj = OptionMaster.objects.create(**old_record)

    return serializer
```

my serialize

```
class OptionMasterSerializer(TemporalModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = OptionMaster
    fields = '__all__'
```

potential temporal serializer

```
class TemporalHyperlinkedModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
vt = serializers.HiddenField(default=datetime(3000, 12, 31, 00, 00, 00, 000000))
vflag = serializers.HiddenField(default=1)

class TemporalModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
vt = serializers.HiddenField(default=datetime(3000, 12, 31, 23, 00, 00, 000000))
vflag = serializers.HiddenField(default=1)

class TemporalModel(models.Model):
vt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='VT')  # Field name made lowercase.
vflag = models.IntegerField(db_column='VFlag')  # Field name made lowercase..
class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to FILTER and UPDATE using a dictionary data.

```
 self.Meta.model.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk, vflag=1).update(**new_record)
```

This was my final working TemporalModelSerializer below

```
    class TemporalModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        vf = serializers.HiddenField(default=timezone.now())
        vt = serializers.HiddenField(default=datetime(3000, 12, 31, 23, 00, 00, 000000))
        vflag = serializers.HiddenField(default=1)
        vu = serializers.HiddenField(default='Theodore')

        class Meta:
            model = None
            fields = '__all__'

        def update(self, instance, validated_data):

            time_now = timezone.now()

            old_record = {}
            new_record = {}

            for (key, value) in validated_data.items():
                old_record[key] = getattr(instance, key)
                new_record[key] = validated_data[key]
                setattr(instance, key, value)

            old_record['vt'] = time_now
            old_record['vflag'] = 0
            new_record['vf'] = time_now

            self.delete_me(old_record)

            self.Meta.model.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk, vflag=1).update(**new_record)

            return instance

        def delete_me(self, old_record):
            obj = self.Meta.model.objects.create(**old_record)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tbh, I have never dealt with such a problem before, but this is somewhat more of database design question than a django-rest one. Hence, without knowing a little bit more about the purpose and relation of these models, I can merely make an estimated guess (as follows).

An intuitive approach of mine would be to implement an additional `IntegerField` called something along the lines of `series_group_id`, which would serve as an identifier of grouped time series and a `created_add` `DateTimeField` the `auto_now_add` flag set to `True`. That way, this field gets populated with the `datetime` value at the moment of creation.

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    # some other stuff like vflag and vt
    goup_id = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

What's more, if you are keeping track of a time series, you are technically not updating your instances but creating new ones. Hence, my approach would be to move your entire logic to the `create` method. In fact, a ModelSerializer provides this kind of behaviour out of the box. The only thing you need to do is add the `group_id` to your serializer's `fields` tuple. As you are using '**all**', the field will automagically appear in your fields as soon as you add it to your model.

In case you need more granular control, you can override the `create` method like so:

```
class OptionMasterViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = OptionMasterSerializer
    paginate_by = None
    queryset = OptionMaster.objects.filter(vflag=1)


    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = OptionMaster.objects.filter(vflag=1)
        contractcode = self.request.query_params.get('contractcode', None)
        if contractcode is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(contractcode=contractcode, vflag=1)
        return queryset

    def create(self, request):
        data = request.get('data', None)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        # some custom logic here in case you need it..
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        return Response({'detail': 'ok'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

#### Limitations

This approach expects that the arriving data comprises the `group_id` of the corresponding time series you are currently tracking.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, I had come across the group_id method implemented by "finiteloopsoftware/django-bitemporal".